# How to use debdiff file to make a local Debian package?

Tags: debian, patch

I had asked [how to apply patch in a debian package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324680/how-to-apply-patch-in-a-debian-package). After that I had tried to figure out patches against interesting packages and was able to get a script that tells that. [cleaning output of a script so it's descending, gives package names and cleanly exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325395/cleaning-output-of-a-script-so-its-descending-gives-package-names-and-cleanly). Now I came to know of something similar to patch called a debdiff which is part of `devscripts`. I saw the manpage (which I couldn't understand or make a head or tail of). I tried various search engine keyword manipulations to get if there is a way to use debdiff to do what we do with patch but came up empty. One of the patches which interests me is https://bugs.debian.org/845173. As can be seen it has a debdiff and not a patch. Conceptually though, both seem similar or/and same. They may or may not be subtle differences that I'm aware of.

My query is would the command be the same — e.g. is

```
$ patch -p1 < ../$whatever.debdiff
```

the same as

```
$ patch -p1 < ../$whatever.patch
```

or are there any differences or anything that I should know/remember to try out?

Answer (score 2):

`debdiff` is a tool, not a file format, and one of the things it *can* produce is a patch. So yes, the command to apply the file in [#845173](https://bugs.debian.org/845173) is simply

```
patch -p1 < debdelta_0.55+nmu1.debdiff
```

You'll probably also find files with `.nmudiff` extensions in your explorations of bugs with patches; these are also plain patches and apply in the same way.