# Applying patches in debian packages - Part 2

Tags: debian, package-management, compiling, patch

I had asked about applying patches [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324680/how-to-apply-patch-in-a-debian-package) . I tried today using the same procedure on a different source-package and it failed. Sharing -

```
~/games $ mkdir decopy

~/games/decopy $ apt-get source decopy

Reading package lists... Done
NOTICE: 'decopy' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/decopy.git
Please use:
git clone https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/decopy.git
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 46.9 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://debian-mirror.sakura.ne.jp/debian unstable/main decopy
0.2-1 (dsc) [1,943 B]
Get:2 http://debian-mirror.sakura.ne.jp/debian unstable/main decopy
0.2-1 (tar) [43.2 kB]
Get:3 http://debian-mirror.sakura.ne.jp/debian unstable/main decopy
0.2-1 (diff) [1,760 B]
Fetched 46.9 kB in 42s (1,103 B/s)
dpkg-source: info: extracting decopy in decopy-0.2
dpkg-source: info: unpacking decopy_0.2.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking decopy_0.2-1.debian.tar.xz
```

Then listing -

```
~/games/decopy $  ls                                                             

decopy-0.2  decopy_0.2-1.debian.tar.xz  decopy_0.2-1.dsc  decopy_0.2.orig.tar.gz
```

Obviously decopy-0.2 is where things are.

`/games/decopy/decopy$ wget https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=854052;filename=use_tqdm_progress.patch;msg=10`

```
~/games/decopy/ $ ─[$] ls

decopy-0.2  decopy_0.2-1.debian.tar.xz  decopy_0.2-1.dsc
decopy_0.2.orig.tar.gz use_tqdm_progress.patch

~/games/decopy $ cd decopy-0.2

~/games/decopy/decopy-0.2 $ patch -p1 < ../use_tqdm_progress.patch

 (Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
patching file decopy/cmdoptions.py
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
patching file decopy/tree.py
Hunk #2 succeeded at 190 (offset -6 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 201 (offset -6 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 303 (offset -6 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 364 (offset -6 lines).
```

Patched it, and now using dch to have another go -

```
  ~/games/decopy/decopy-0.2 $ dch -n "Apply patch given in #854052".

  ~/games/decopy/decopy-0.2 $
```

Now the directory didn't change, apparently because this package is not a *native* package like dpkg is/was .

What are the recommended steps here ?

Also is there a way to know which package is a debian *native* package and which are not ? Any tests or something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "3.0 (quilt)" package (see `debian/source/format`), so you'll need to use `quilt` to manage the patch. Revert the patch:

```
patch -R -p1 < ../use_tqdm_progress.patch
```

then create the appropriate structure:

```
mkdir -p debian/patches
cp ../use_tqdm_progress.patch debian/patches
echo use_tqdm_progress.patch >> debian/patches/series
```

You should refresh the patch:

```
quilt push
quilt refresh
```

Your `dch` is fine, as is the fact that the directory name didn't change. You can build the package now:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

As far as native packages go, you can spot a native package by the fact that it doesn't have a hyphen in its version (generally speaking). Here, the version is 0.2-1, so it's not a native package. Inside the package, `debian/source/format` would be "3.0 (native)" for a native package.

Comment: umm... shouldn't we somehow bump the version number, something like `decopy_0.2-1+1nmu' or something for us to know it's not from Debian universe, but self-manufactured debian package.

Comment: @Wumpus thanks for the edit! In this particular instance there was no file to clobber, but you're right in general.

Comment: @shirish that's what `dch -n` does; for a non-native package it only needs to add an entry to `debian/changelog`, it doesn't rename the directory. (Even in the native case it doesn't really need to, it just does it to match what `dpkg-source -x` would produce.)

Comment: aha...ok, so now I know a bit more :)

Comment: It was a quilt package with no patches? Is that just because you have to specify some kind of patch format, even when you don't have any, to satisfy the package builder?

Comment: @Wumpus you don't specify a patch format, you specify a source format; and the only valid formats are "1.0" (which is deprecated), "3.0 (native)" (for native packages) and "3.0 (quilt)" (for everything else). The `dpkg-source` manpage has the details.